# Building a Rest Request with Dynamic Segments

Tags: rest, go

I am trying to test a handler, the handler is below:

```
router.HandleFunc("/address/{id}", DeletePerson).Methods("DELETE")
```

The request that I created was:

```
request, _ := http.NewRequest("DELETE", "/address/2", nil)
DeletePerson(response, request)
```

using github.com/gorilla/mux I attempted to extract the "id" with

```
params = mux.Vars(request)
item := params["id"]

returns:  params = map[] and item = ""
```

However, if I call DeletePerson with the curl command:

```
curl -X DELETE http://localhost:8000/address/2
```

I get:  params = map["id"] and item = "2"

HOW Do I construct a URL request that get the results like Curl?

Comment: Please post the response header status. To see if your request if fulfilled correctly or its is throwing some HTTP error. So do not skip the errors when creating a request in test case.

Comment: Print the error in this code snippet `request, err := http.NewRequest("DELETE", "/address/2", nil)`

Answer (score 0):

If you call `DeletePerson` directly, the request doesn't pass through the router, which parses the parameters in the request path.

Also, `http.NewRequest` returns a client request. Either add scheme and host to the URL and pass the request to `http.Client.Do`, or use [httptest.NewRequest](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#NewRequest) to create a server request directly.

> NewRequest returns a new incoming server Request, suitable for passing to an http.Handler for testing.

```
request := httptest.NewRequest("DELETE", "/address/2", nil)
mux.ServeHTTP(response, request)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you don't put the full URL in the request. And I guess that you ignore the error while executing the request. If you don't put the full URL it will complains something like this: `panic: Delete /address/2: unsupported protocol scheme ""`

The following code works OK in my machine:

```
package main

import "net/http"

func main() {
    r, err := http.NewRequest("DELETE", "http://localhost:8080/address/2", nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if _, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(r); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)